# Unable to access state inside interval

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am unable to access the state within an interval. Here I want to access counter inside interval when the counter gets equal to 10 I want to stop it.

**Note:** Here I don't want to put an interval inside useEffect because I need to start the interval in a specific time, by handling an event.

```
export default props => {

  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  const startInterval = () => {
    const timeout = setInterval(() => {
      setCounter(counter + 1);
      console.log("counter: ", counter); // alway return 0
      if(counter === 10) clearInterval(timeout);

    }, 1000);
  };

}
```

Comment: How and where are you using `startInterval` function

Comment: @patrick "props is neither a hook nor a component" ... yes, it's the props object?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts thank you, but the compiles and execute as well, it is a function component with a props param exported. problem is in `interval`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I am seeing here even your `setCounter(counter+1)` wont update, because of lexical scope. So you have to change it like this:

```
setCounter(counter => counter + 1);
```

Also because of lexical scope you wont access counter to check condition, so you have to make a variable and update that inside functional component by asigning counter to it, then check it with if condition.

**Complete Code code:**

```
let myCounter = 0;
let timeout = null;
export default CounterApp = props => {

  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  // Also don't forget this
  useEffect(()=> {
    return ()=> clearInterval(timeout);
  }, []);      

  myCounter = counter;
  const startInterval = () => {
    timeout = setInterval(() => {
      setCounter(counter => counter + 1);
      console.log("counter: ", myCounter); // counter always return 0 but myCounter the updated value
      if(myCounter === 10) clearInterval(timeout);

    }, 1000);
  };

}
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me a lot and worked for me, but Still I don't know why we can not access `counter` inside `interval`.

Comment: Answer has edited, as mentioned don't forget to clear interval, when unmounting Component.

Answer (score 3):

I came across this exact problem not too long ago. Hooks don't work exactly as you'd expect in relation to setInterval. I [found the solution on Dan Abramov's blog](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/): You can `useRef` to combine multiple `useEffect`s. Through his `useInterval` implementation you can also start and stop the interval by setting the timer to `null`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [time, setTime] = useState(null); // timer doesn't run initially

  useInterval(() => {
    // Your custom logic here
    setCount(count + 1);
  }, time);

  return <>
     <h1>{count}</h1>
     <div onClick={() => setTime(1000)}>Start</div>
     <div onClick={() => setTime(null)}>Stop</div>
  </>;
}
```

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

function useInterval(callback, delay) {
  const savedCallback = useRef();

  // Remember the latest callback.
  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  // Set up the interval.
  useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
      savedCallback.current();
    }
    if (delay !== null) {
      let id = setInterval(tick, delay);
      return () => clearInterval(id);
    }
  }, [delay]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you to answer, but this looks complicate to me, I just want to know why `counter` isn't accessible inside interval